# Trying to understand what .External() is?

Tags: c++, r

I am fairly unfamiliar with R, but hoping to use it to try and use a particular package. I have installed the following package from R-Forge:

```
install.packages("ecomodtools", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I received the following error:

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ecomodtools’

and learned that I needed "RTools" to install it. So I got RTools and I was able to install this package.

I have included some sample code below that can be copy-pasted, but when I run this code I get an error in regards to .External() which is what I am trying to understand:

```
library(ecomodtools)

# 2D Gaussian dispersal function defined according to Clark et al. (1999)
# Used in the Monte Carlo integration
genexp.disp <- function(from, to, params)
{
  r.sq <- (from[1] - to[1])^2 + (from[2] - to[2])^2
  (1.0 / (pi * params[1]^2)) * exp(-(r.sq / params[1]^2))
}

# Monte Carlo integration settings
max.prob <- .Machine$double.eps^0.25
initial.step <- 10000
step.size <- 10000
max.runs <- 1000000
max.rel.var <- .Machine$double.eps^0.25

# Boundary condition
boundary <- "restricting"

# Alpha parameter setting
params <- c(1.0)

# Make a small grid (3 x 3) for testing purposes
x.coords <- seq(0.0, 3.0, 1.0)
y.coords <- seq(0.0, 3.0, 1.0)
test.grid <- MakeGridFromCoords(x.coords, y.coords)

# Calculate the transition matrices for each different approximation method

AA.mc <- LatticeTransitionProbs(
  x1 = test.grid$x1, x2 = test.grid$x2, y1 = test.grid$y1, y2 = test.grid$y2,
  func = genexp.disp, approx.method = "AA", boundary = boundary, max.prob = max.prob,
  initial.step = initial.step, step.size = step.size, max.rel.var = max.rel.var, max.runs = max.runs, params = params)
```

ERROR:

> Error in .External("MakeGridFromCoords", x = as.double(x), y = as.double(y),  :
>   "MakeGridFromCoords" not available for .External() for package "ecomodtools"

In the source code, this .External() function seems to be in all of the functions and I have found the definition of this to be "Functions to pass R objects to compiled C/C++ code that has been loaded into R".

So I am hoping that somebody might be able to give a different explanation of what's going on here. I think that this issue is that I don't have the source C/C++ code so maybe the .External() is not sending the information to anything in particular. But again, I am fresh to R, so it's not clear to me what's going on.

Comment: I am surprised that this compiles. [ecomodtools](https://rdrr.io/rforge/ecomodtools/) is apparently quite old and not under active development and has, in the past, been [flagged as 'does not compile with new R versions'](https://github.com/ropensci/software-review/issues/188). It was clearly intended this function to be used in the way you use it, but the syntax of how `.External()` can be used has changed since. `.External()` is for handing R objects to C++ etc. functions called from R (like `.Call()`). See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/CallExternal.html).